# Is it worth writing for Honeycomb yet?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm just one person who writes both iOS and Andorid apps in his free time. I have a few Android apps that I think would be good candidates for updates that allow them to run natively on Honeycomb.

But, since I don't have a Honeycomb tablet and I don't feel comfortable releasing an app I've only tested on the emulator, is it worth the investment of both time and money (for purchasing a tablet) in writing an app for Honeycomb? Can any developers who have been in a similar situation as me comment on whether they've seen their downloads increase as a result of a Honeycomb-compliant update? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is really a *programming* question, as it pertains more to business development (I think), but I'll give it a shot.

Judging by your explanation, I'd guess you don't have 5,500 users yet. I could be entirely wrong about that, and if so I apologise. But we know that 5,500 developers received tablets from I/O. That means that *at the very least*, you have a market of 5,500 people.

Most large companies have the same mindset as @momo-- that it isn't worth it. So the "tablet-optimised" area of the Market remains prime real estate that is fairly simple to get into. Just write a competent app that is optimised for Honeycomb.

Now, my point isn't that you'll get 5,500 new users; that really depends on the app. My point is two-fold: first, that your market is (likely) larger than your current user count (and therefore worth considering); second, developing for that market now will be much more effective than developing for it when the market has expanded, because of the recognition you'll receive. Early adopters tend to be rewarded pretty well.

I can't advise your case specifically; I don't know many of the details. How big of a financial risk is it to buy a tablet? How much of the tablet experience can your app benefit from? How many pressing issues does your codebase have for the phone version? How much time do you have to devote to the tablet experience? I can go on and on, and these issues all counterbalance each other and are weighted differently.

I went to I/O, so I got a tablet, so I'll try to support tablets for my apps. A lot of people have to decide whether to sink $500 into dev or not; my advice is, ask yourself how likely it is that you'll make your $500 back. You should already have a good idea; you already have a phone version on the market. Once you know how likely it is, you know whether it's a good investment or not.

Comment: You right that there are very few apps with more than 5500 users but there even fewer apps that rewarded 500$ to their dev with the economic model of phone develOpment.

Comment: My point isn't that there are few apps that corner the market (that seems obvious?). My point was really that there are very few apps that are highlighted to a substantially large market. Assuming they charge $1 per download, they need 10% of the *absolute smallest* possible size for the market to break even. That's not counting users who buy twice, once for phone and once for tablet. I think the publicity will probably offset the size of the market.

Answer (score 3):

Our company develop several apps for our clients and none of them have asked us to upgrade to Honeycomb.

Part of the reasons is simply that the [Honeycomb market distribution](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) is still too low (0.4%, 0.7% and 0.2% for each version of honeycomb per Android website) to justify any development and investment as you have mentioned above. However, if you want to gain familiarity of the features and API of Honeycomb then it's always good to invest your time developing for Honeycomb

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target Google TV, the `Fragment`s stuff is great.

Comment: You can use Fragments in pre-Honeycomb too. You just have to reference the Android Compatibility Package (Can be downloaded via the SDK manager). When you want to release the app on a Honeycomb platform, you just replace the imports.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my distribution statistics (267008 total installs)

> Android 2.2   - 50.3%
>   Android 2.3.3+    - 27.8%
>   Android 2.1   - 13.7%
>   Android 1.6   - 3.5%
>   Android 1.5   - 2.4%
>   Android 3.1   - 0.6%
>   Android 2.3   - 0.5%
>   Android 3.0   - 0.2%
>   Android 1.1   - 0.1%
>   Android 2.0.1 - 0.1%

So, if you're selling apps and just looking from the profit-point of view I think Honeycomb is not yet relevant.

But, on the other side, as an Honeycomb user it makes me happy to find an application wich is fited to Android 3.x already. Further from the developers side of view it's probably not bad to keep the finger on the pulse of time

Comment: If you sold your app for 1 buck you could buy 4 Honeycomb tablets from the profits on 3.0/3.1 devices alone. Thus to break even based on 1 Honeycomb tablet you'd need to sell 62,500 $1 apps.

I've got a free app that seems more techie-friendly; the breakdown is such:`
Android 2.3.3+ 45.4%
Android 2.2 35.6%
Android 2.1 7.1%
Android 3.1 5.8%
Android 1.6 1.0%
Android 2.3 0.8%
Android 3.0 0.6%
Android 1.5 0.4%
Android 2.0.1 0.1%`

The sampling is smaller though, at 3908 total installs. Could it be that lesser-known apps are more likely to be found by a techie crowd?